# Highchart not rendering data from dynamically created array array

Tags: javascript, arrays, highcharts

I am using Firebase Realtime Database to get data to render in Highchart. I have declared an empty array.

```
    arrY = [];
```

And then inside a function, I push the value for x-axis along with a timestamp to the array.

```
   arrY.push([time, parseFloat(tempC)]);
```

Then when initiating the Highchart when I assign the array to the series, the chart is not rendered (no error message in the console)

```
           series: [{
                name: 'Temperature',
                data: arrY
            }]
```

However, If I hardcode an array with it's value and timestamp and assign it to the highchart it gets rendered

```
    a = [[1591815122, 28],[1591815141, 28],[1591815161, 28],[1591815180, 28],[1591815200, 28]];
```

and

```
           series: [{
                name: 'Temperature',
                data: arrY
            }]
```

when I log both the array in the console both are displayed as arrays but why is one working and the other one not working? Console Output in the picture below

[image: Console Output]

Answer (score 1):

The problem which you are struggling to is related to JavaScript Asynchronous. Notice that when you console.log the `arrY` it is an empty array. You need to delay the chart rendering until the data will be downloaded from the server.

Currently, something like this happens:

1. The array is defined,
2. The chart is rendering with an empty array,
3. Data is downloaded and pushed to the array,